# CGPointMake! Coding error message

Tags: iphone, xcode, message

Im building a simple game app, where you have to move a ball away from another one. However Im having an issue with my code, please help. When I build and run it I get 2 error messages. I don't understand what the problem is.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//(X speed, Y speed) vvv
pos = CGPointMake(5.0,4.0);///////// this part here I get an error message saying assigning to CGPoint * (aka 'struct CGPoint*') from incompatible type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint')
}

- (IBAction)start {
[startbutton setHidden:YES];
randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.03) target:(self) selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)onTimer {
[self checkCollision];

enemy.center = CGPointMake(enemy.center.x+pos->x,enemy.center.y+pos->y);

if (enemy.center.x > 320 || enemy.center.x < 0)
    pos->x = -pos->x;

if (enemy.center.y > 480 || enemy.center.y < 0)
    pos->y = -pos->y;

}

-(void)checkCollision {

if( CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame))
{

[randomMain invalidate];
[startbutton setHidden:NO];

CGRect frame = [player frame];
frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
frame.origin.y = 326.0;
[player setFrame:frame];

CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
frame2.origin.x =137.0f;
frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
[enemy setFrame:frame2];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lost!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Were Hit! Try Again"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}



}

-(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *myTOuch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
player.center = [myTouch locationInView:self.view];      /////// Here also I get an error message saying Assigning to 'CGPoint' (aka struct CGPoint') form incompatible type 'id'

////////////////// Also with that error message is Class method '+locationalView' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
}

@end
```

Comment: Code Snippet: UITouch *myTOuch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

is the big O a mistake of you in your real code or just here in the snippet of the code? Because you are trying to invoke on myTouch, not on myTOuch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ViewController.h file, Write this declaration.

```
CGPoint pos;
```

In your ViewController.m file, replace pos.x instead of pos->x and pos.y instead of pos->y.

Answer (score 8):

In your .h file how did you create the `pos` variable?
I think you added a *  :

```
CGPoint *pos;
```

remove the *  :

```
CGPoint pos;
```

*EDIT* (thanks Jonathan Grynspan)

Why do you use the -> operator? I personally never saw it in Objective-C code.
Try changing them to dots:

```
if (enemy.center.x > 320 || enemy.center.x < 0)
    pos.x *= -1;
```

Comment: Might want to comment on his use of the arrow operator (`->`) as well.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan && Juzzz: the -> is perfectly valid in objective C, it is inherited from C/C++. a->b means: Structure dereference ("member b of object pointed to by a") and you can also do a->*b which means: Member pointed to by b of object pointed to by a. This does not nec means he is doing it valid tho. Just saying it's not wrong just old-school

Comment: @TotumusMaximus It's not valid if `pos` is a `CGPoint` rather than a `CGPoint *`. It's still only valid on pointers and pointer-like types.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: and thus my last sentence saying this is not nec the case for him. Just informing you to these operators existence ^^

Comment: @TotumusMaximus I'm well aware of them. They're not appropriate *here* which is what my comment was about.

Answer (score 1):

When you see a * between your var name and the Class of which you try to instantiate an object it means it is a pointer of that object. When the * is not there it is not a pointer but a hard value.

You mixed up those things and forgot to remove the * from your CGPoint property inside your .h file. Fix that and the error is gone.

CGPoint *pos ---> CGPoint pos